# bash command line can not read command properly

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, console, tty

I have a problem about bash terminal, and it made me crazy, and i don't know why.
It is about the terminal, let me describe it as below:
At first the prompt is like:

```
[12:00]ruan:~>
```

But when i input characters consecutively (for example, assume i input a lot of A), the weird thing happened:

```
AAA:00]ruan:~ > AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

As you can see, character i input starts from the **beginning of the line**, which made my command unreadable. I don't know how can this happen. Is it related to stty, inputrc or something else?
/br
ruan

my tty config is like:

```
:)[11:38]ruan:~ > stty -a
speed 38400 baud; 25 rows; 80 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

i have setup PS1 like:

```
NORMAL="\033[0m"
RED="\033[0;31m"
RED_BOLD="\033[1;31m"
GREEN="\033[0;32m"
GREEN_BOLD="\033[1;32m"
YELLOW="\033[0;33m"
YELLOW_BOLD="\033[1;33m"
BLUE="\033[0;34m"
BLUE_BOLD="\033[1;34m"
MAGENTA="\033[0;35m"
MAGENTA_BOLD="\033[1;35m"
CYAN="\033[0;36m"
CYAN_BOLD="\033[1;36m"

function smile_or_frown() {
    [[ $? = 0 ]] && echo -e "${CYAN_BOLD}:)" || echo -e "${MAGENTA_BOLD}:("
}
export PS1="\$(smile_or_frown)$BLUE_BOLD[\A]$GREEN_BOLD\u:$RED_BOLD\w$YELLOW_BOLD\$(parse_git_branch)$NORMAL > "
```

Comment: Have you tried to recreate the problem in a different client?

Comment: @d3c0y, yes, i first found it at office, and i think maybe someone screw up the environment. But i found it also exist on my Mac at home when i decide to use bash instead of zsh. BTW, there is no such phenomenon when i use zsh.

Comment: What is `PS1` (the command prompt), set to?

Comment: @Leffler, please see my edit update, i have put it just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose all ANSI escape sequences in `\[ .. \]` to signal to Bash that these don't take up space on the terminal.

They have to be in the format string itself, and can not be part of data expanded at prompt time (but can be in data expanded at assignment time).

For example:

```
export PS1="\[$BLUE_BOLD\][\A]\[$GREEN_BOLD\]\u:\[$RED_BOLD\]\w\[$YELLOW_BOLD\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$NORMAL\] > "
```

To make this work for smile_or_frown, you have to refactor it into two functions, one for the color and one for the text, so that you can do `"\[\$(smile_color)\]\$(smile_type)"`

Comment: "can not be part of expanded data" is a bit misleading. They could be part of `$BLUE_BOLD` & friends, but not part of `\$(smile_color)`. But I can't think of a simple way to explain the difference, either.

Comment: Not necessarily all escape sequences need to be enclosed in `\[`/'\]'; just those that do not take up any space on the command line. This tells `bash` that although the characters are present in the *value* of `PS1`, they are not visible in the string that is actually displayed in the terminal.

Comment: thank you guys, you are right. but i still have something unclear. As in my question, in function 'smile_or_frown', if i just use 'echo' instead of 'echo -e', the result will be like: "\[\e[1;36m\]:)[10:12]eruahao@eselnts1171:~", it seems the color is not explained. why can't i put color info in a function output. when $(smile_or_frown) is expanded, i think they are all the same, but actually not.

Comment: @ruanhao in `"\$(cmd)"`, the output of cmd is treated as data, not as code. This is just like in e.g. ruby where `var="1+2"; print var` doesn't print `3`, because the contents of `var` is treated as data and not as code.

Comment: @thatotherguy, treated as code? i do not understand that. i thought it should be like "eval PS1" when bash is ready to show command prompt. So i thought whether it is from function output or writing out literally, the result should be like the same. am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: @ruanhao If you want to look at the Bash source, it's in `y.tab.c` function `decode_prompt_string`. The code that handles `\[\]` runs before anything in the string is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to check current terminal columns (width)

```
tput cols
```

And use this to set it to 80 cols:

```
stty cols 80
```

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question it appears your complex `PS1` is causing this. You can reset your `PS1` to a simple:

```
PS1='$>'
```

too fix this issue.

Comment: like: 
:)[11:38]ruan:~ > tput cols
80

Comment: Try setting `PS1='$>'`

Comment: yes, PS1=$> works, is there something wrong with my customization?

Comment: These escape codes vary a lot depending on type of terminal so I'm not sure which one is causing problem.